# Can I found solution to make zxing compatible with Android 2.2

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code, android-support-library, android-2.2-froyo

I've got problem of compatibility with **zxing** due to my minimum sdk version (sdk version 8)

Does anyone know how can I scan **QrCode** in my application is using **ActionBarSherlock** with a fragment design.

How can I scan QRCode. Which library can I use to do that, knowing it have to be compatible with **sdk version 8** !!

I really need help for that one.

Thanks.

Comment: Considering that the Barcode Scanner app has been around since Android 1.0, I feel quite confident that the Barcode Scanner app runs on API Level 8.

Comment: Android 0.9 technically! although the current build does in fact require 4+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to go back to about the Barcode Scanner 4.3 release in Subversion, which is the last one that was compatible with Android < 2.3. The current version requires 4+.

Although you would be going back and losing some enhancements and bug fixes, it is still pretty similar and probably sufficient for your purpose.

Only 1.7% of Android devices are on 2.2 or earlier. Seriously consider not supporting them.
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: It was one of my client request...
I finally succeed to make him change his mind about the version YAY!
Thanks for the answer

Comment: "Beginning in September, 2013, devices running versions older than Android 2.2 do not appear in this data because those devices do not support the new Google Play Store app."

Comment: True, the question was about 2.2 rather than older than 2.2, but the link above shows 2.2 is now only 1.3%.

Comment: "1.7% of 1 Billion devices that's quite a lot" This is my client answer.